# How do I determine the value of a Ninject Binding from a Web Request's URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ninject

Here's roughly what I have:

**Api Controller**

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    public MyController(IServiceThatNeedsPrinicipal myService)
    {
    }
}
```

**MyService**

```
public class MyService: IServiceThatNeedsPrinicipal 
{
    public MyService(IMyPrincipal myService)
    {
    }
}
```

**IMyPrincipal**

```
public interface IMyPrincipal : IPrincipal {}
```

This self-hosted website will be getting a `POST` request like:

```
localhost:9005/Start?UserId=1
```

What I'd like to do is:

```
this.Bind<IMyPrincipal>().ToMethod(c =>
{
    int userId = /* Get UserId from Request -- How do I do this inside a NinjectModule? */
    IMyPrincipal mp = CodeToGetMyPrincipalFromUserId(userId); /* I know how to do this */
    return mp;
});
```

I tried:

```
var request = HttpContext.Current.Items["MS_HttpRequestMessage"] as HttpRequestMessage;
var queryPairs = request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();
```

And going through the queryPairs, but at run time `HttpContext.Current` is `null`.

Any ideas - how do I get the value out of the url and accessible in my Ninject Module?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this functions as I want.  Seems to work.  (It's ugly, of course.)

I made a class with a static property:

```
public class RequestMessage
{
    public static HttpRequestMessage Contents { get; set; }
}
```

And then I just added a DelegatingHandler to set it.

```
public class RequestMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        RequestMessage.Contents = request;
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

And registered it:

```
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new RequestMessageHandler());
```

And changed my code to use:

```
var request = RequestMessage.Contents;
```